# Webpack plugins - when to call doResolve and when callback?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

Every webpack resolve plugin follows the following structure:

```
resolver.plugin(this.source, function(request, callback) {
    if (something) {
         resolver.doResolve(target, obj, "aliased with mapping '" + name + "': '" + ...)
    } else {
         callback(...);
    }
```

Can anyone please explain when I should call `doResolve` and when callback. I've found this phrase in the webpack docs:

> To pass the request to other resolving plugins, use the
>   this.doResolve(types: String|String[], request: Request, callback)
>   method

However, I don't know what to make of it. It seems that `doResolve` starts the process from the start. Here is how the stack looks like in `doResolve`:

[image]

You can see that the stages started from the beginning. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webpack runs all plugins for the resolver using `applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1` method. This method runs all plugins in the succession - the next plugin is run only after the current plugin has finished executing. 
The `bail` here means that the sequence is interrupted as soon as one plugin returns an error. This approach is also known as "fail-fast". But `BailResult` means that the sequence is also interrupted as soon as one plugin returns a result. You can see it from the sources:

```
applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 = function applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1(name, param, callback) {
    var plugins = this._plugins[name];
    if(!plugins || plugins.length === 0) return callback();
    var i = 0;
    var _this = this;
    var innerCallback = function next(err, result) {
        // if the plugin returned an error or a result - break
        if(arguments.length > 0) return callback(err, result);
        i++;
        // if all plugins have run - break
        if(i >= plugins.length) {
            return callback();
        }
        // trigger next plugin - continue
        plugins[i].call(_this, param, innerCallback);
    });
    plugins[0].call(this, param, innerCallback);
};
```

So from this code you can see that as soon as you call `callback` inside the plugin with parameters you **interrupt** the sequence. The first parameter is the error, the second parameter is the result. This is in line with how `Node.js` expects the callbacks signature. If you call the `callback` without parameters, the sequence is **continued**.

Now, you can also call `doResolve` which will run the entire sequences of plugins again. This is usually done when you apply some changes to the request and so you want to give a chance to all other plugins again to react to the new request. As your current plugin will be called again on the next `doResolve` round make sure to construct it so that it prevents recursion. Webpack guards again recursion but only if `path`, `request`, `query` `directory` and `module` match as can be seen from the sources:

```
Resolver.prototype.doResolve = function doResolve(type, request, message, callback) {
    var resolver = this;
    var stackLine = type + ": (" + request.path + ") " +
        (request.request || "") + (request.query || "") +
        (request.directory ? " directory" : "") +
        (request.module ? " module" : "");
    var newStack = [stackLine];
    if(callback.stack) {
        newStack = callback.stack.concat(newStack);
        if(callback.stack.indexOf(stackLine) >= 0) {
            // Prevent recursion
            var recursionError = new Error("Recursion in resolving\nStack:\n  " + newStack.join("\n  "));
```

And inside the callback to the `doResolve` you usually call `callback()` to break from the current round of plugins since they have had their chance to react to the updated request:

```
resolver.plugin(this.source, function(request, callback) {
    if (something) {
         resolver.doResolve(target, obj, 
               "aliased with mapping '" + name + "': '" + ..., 
               function() { callback(error, result) }
         )
```